# How to evaluate the definite integral of an N-th power of a funcion?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let us suppose that we have a function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ whose indefinite integral we know.

Is there some procedure how to compute the **definite** integral of $f^n$?

In the general case:

$$
\int_{a}^{b} f^n(x) dx
$$

the first thing that comes to my mind is to derive with respect to $n$ and see if I can integrate it back to something meaningful:

$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial n} \int_{a}^{b} f^n(x) dx =  \int_{a}^{b} f^{n}(x) \ln(f(x)) dx
$$

But I do not know how to integrate the transformed integral. I tried integration by parts but it did not lead me anywhere.

If there is no simple answer in the general case, are there some tools to **approximate** the integral of the $n$-th power or provide **bounds** in terms of the original integral?

Comment: $\partial/\partial n$ seems legit if $n\in\mathbf{N}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even a bounding in terms of the original integral is impossible: Let be $[a,b]=[-1,1]$, $f(x)=x.$
$$\int_{-1}^1 x\,dx = 0,$$
$$\int_{-1}^1 x^2\,dx > 0.$$

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. I should have added a non-negativity assumption or something similar.